# Qt adding drop shadow effect for QLabel using QGraphicsDropShadow

Tags: c++

I have to apply drop shadow for multiple QLabel in my Application. I used QGraphicsDropShadowEffect and it is working fine, if i am adding it for one QLabel. I tried applying the same Graphics effect for two QLabels.

```
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
effect->setColor(Qt::white);
effect->setBlurRadius(0);
effect->setXOffset(1);
effect->setYOffset(0);
QLabel* label = new QLabel();
label->setText("QLabel1");
label->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
QLabel* label2 = new QLabel();
label2->setText("QLabel2");
label2->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
```

In this case,the shadow effect is applied only to label2.
I tried creating two different QGraphicsDropShadowEffect objects and setting the QLabels with that.

```
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
effect->setColor(Qt::white);
QLabel* label = new QLabel();
label->setText("QLabel1");
label->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* effect1 = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
effect1->setColor(Qt::white);
QLabel* label2 = new QLabel();
label2->setText("QLabel2");
label2->setGraphicsEffect(effect1);
```

In this case, Application is crashing in QRasterPaintEngine::transformChanged() call.

Any idea on how to fix this issue?
I am using qt 5.3.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Was just trying to solve this myself. As much as this solution pains me it's the best I came up with quickly. Use QList to help yourself out here:

```
// List instances containing labels and drop shadows
QList<QLabel*> label_list_;
QList<QGraphicsDropShadowEffect*> shadow_list_;

// Get all UI labels and apply shadows
label_list_ = this->findChildren<QLabel*>();
foreach(QLabel *lbl, label_list_) {
    shadow_list_.append(new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect);
    shadow_list_.back()->setBlurRadius(10);
    shadow_list_.back()->setOffset(3, 3);
    lbl->setGraphicsEffect(shadow_list_.back());
}
```

If don't want all UI labels in your list you can add manually with `append`